# Returning function vs returning object

Tags: javascript

In javascript, there are two patterns and I would like to weight the benefits of using one vs the other. What is the difference between returning an object vs returning a function, for example:

```
var returnFunction = function(name,age){
  var n = name;
  var a = name;
  return function(){
    anotherFunc : function(){},
    oneMoreFunc : function(){}
  }
}
```

I returned a function containing two more functions, and access to private variables name and age. I understand that I can invoke returnfunction, and I know that I can use it like a constructor. I want to know, what are the benefits of this style vs:

```
var returnObject = function(name,age){
  var n = name;
  var a = age;
  return {
    anotherFunc:function(){},
    oneMoreFunc:function(){},
  };
}
```

- Is there a performance penalty?
- Is it just a matter of style?
- Are there any benefits to one or the other, or am I just overthinking this?

**edit:**

With regards to option A, I was referencing this particular syntax from Javascript: The Good Parts

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

String.method('deentityify', function() {

    // The entity table. It maps entity names to
    // characters.

    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };

    // Return the deentityify method.

    return function() {

        // This is the deentityify method. It calls the string
        // replace method, looking for substrings that start
        // with '&' and end with ';'. If the characters in
        // between are in the entity table, then replace the
        // entity with the character from the table. It uses
        // a regular expression (Chapter 7).

        return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
            function(a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());
```

Option A was a contrived example meant to replicate this syntax.

Comment: `functions` will always eat more resources than calling an `object`.

Comment: The first won't work. It returns a function that does nothing but define and discard two more functions.

Comment: @NicholasHazel what if the function is in an object?

Comment: Then you shouldn't use a `function` to call a `function` if you don't need to. It's redundant. You will do that very often in `js`, but if you don't have to, don't.

Comment: How do you figure that the first option would work? You are trying to use object literal syntax inside a function, that will just give you a syntax error.

Comment: @Guffa The labels actually are valid syntax. The anonymous function declarations aren't, though, and labels don't make them function expressions. Also I'm not sure you can stuff a label inside a comma expression. Yep. It's just plain wrong :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about comparing a non-working option to a working one.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's not the property names that is the problem as they are interpreted as labels. After those come function expressions, which gives a syntax error when used like that.

Comment: @aclave1 the difference is the first one won't work. Have you even tested the code you posted here?

Comment: In javascript the good parts, in chapter 4.12 : Modules he returns a function for his deeintityify method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant A doesn't work. It's a syntax error.

So what you're really comparing:

```
var returnFunction = function(name,age){
    var n = name;
    var a = name;

    // return a function that returns
    return function(){

        // logic to construct the object
        var obj = {
            anotherFunc : function(){},
            oneMoreFunc : function(){}
        }

        // return the object
        return obj;
    }
}

// vs.
var returnObject = function(name,age){
    var n = name;
    var a = age;

    // return the object directly
    return {
        anotherFunc:function(){},
        oneMoreFunc:function(){},
    };
}
```

It depends on what does the object look like.

In most cases, you'd go with option B. Just return a simple object.
I don't know anything other than V8, but in V8 it looks like this:

-> new scope
-> assign some vars
-> create a function
-> compile the code in that function
-> return the function, close the scope
-> run the function
-> new scope
-> create the object
-> return the object, close the scope

vs.

-> new scope
-> assign some vars
-> create the object
-> return the object, close the scope

Obviously the first has more steps, but the speed difference is insignificant.

However, there are cases in which it would simply be impractical to return a complex object with multiple nested properties and native functions that have to be initialized. Case in which it is much more useful to generate the object and return it on-a-need basis. Which is option A.

But, better than having option A, and if you intend to make interventions on that returned object, it's just nicer to make it a class:

```
var returnObjectClass = function(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.class = class;
    this.anotherFunc = function(){};
    this.oneMoreFunc = function(){};
    return this;
}
```

You can read more here: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: There are no classes in javascript. If *returnObjectClass* is intended to be called as a constructor, it's convention for its name to start with a capital letter. Functions are only constructors when called with *new*, they return *this* by default so there's no need for a return statement and it's convention to not include one. `this.anotherFunc:function(){};` should perahps be `this.anotherFunc = function(){};`, but methods should be on the constructor's prototype otherwise it's just an object.

Comment: Everything you said is right. I'm correcting now.